# Split a Cell Array

Tags: matlab

I have a 150X1 cell array. Within the array there are multiple data types. The first cell contains `0.9VA = 1.012207`; the second: `0.9VA_CLK = 0.020752`; and so on like this (for the most part). I would like to split the cell into two cells using the `=` as the delimiter. Thus, {1,1}: `0.9VA` and {1,2}: 1.012207; {2,1}: `0.9VA_CLK` and {2,2}: `0.020752`; so on and so forth. I have tried converting them to strings and then using `strsplit`; however, I run into problems because the string arrays are variable in size.

If there is any other information that I can provide please let me know. Thank you for your help and time in advance.

[image]

Comment: When you say "The first cell contains `0.9VA = 1.012207`", is that a string (or character array)?

Comment: It doesn't specify. Sorry, I am in my infancy for this language. I have seen a cell contain something like `1X3 string` in the past, but in this case it is just the raw data in the cell.

Comment: I added an image. This is what I see when I open the 150X1 array.

Comment: What does `class(my_cell_array{1})` say? What does `size(my_cell_array{1})` say? (of course, replace `my_cell_array` with the name of your cell array...)

Comment: Ahh, perfect! `class(my_cell_array{1})` = `char`. `size(my_cell_array{1})` = 1 38.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can indeed apply `strsplit` to each of the strings (char arrays) in the cell array. To do so, you can use [`cellfun`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html):

```
c{1} = '0.9VA = 1.012207';
c{2} = '0.9VA_CLK = 0.020752';
c{3} = 'CSIPhgenSWoffList = [0, 0, 0, 0]';
c{4} = 'SomethingElse = [0.020752, 0.24564]';
c = cellfun(@(x)strsplit(x,'='),c,'UniformOutput',false);
c = cat(1,c{:});
```

I use a small example cell array `c` here, containing four strings, I hope this is representative. I apply `strplit` to each cell in `c` using `cellfun(x,'=')`, which splits at the equal sign and returns a cell array with cell arrays. That is, each string in `c` is turned into a cell array with 2 strings (e.g. `'0.9VA '` and `' 1.012207'`. This does leave some spaces at the beginning and end of the strings.

The next line, `cat`, converts this cell array of cell arrays into a two-dimensional cell array. The final output is a cell array `c` containing the same number of rows as the original cell array, and with 2 columns. The first column corresponds to the part before the equal sign, the second column to the part after the equal sign.

To remove the spaces, you can use `cellfun` again, with [`strtrim`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strtrim.html):

```
c = cellfun(@strtrim,c,'UniformOutput',false);
```

Comment: Okay, but here is the issue I run into and it is the issue I had when I was trying to do this as string arrays as I noted above (which I thought that having them in cell arrays would be different). The number of columns is variable; so when I use the `cat` function, I get the error: "Dimensions of arrays being concatenated are not consistent." Any thoughts on how to overcome this issue?

Comment: @DymaxionFuller: can you give an example of one of those strings that is different? The examples you give are all "X = Y", and should be split into 3 elements by `strsplit`. Do you have any empty cells maybe?

Comment: Sure. Here is a 1X6 cell my_array{99,1}: `CSIPhgenSWoffList = [0,0,0,0]`. The others are in that same typical format, with some extending out to 130 columns.

Comment: I guess there could be spaces in that array? Such as `CSIPhgenSWoffList = [0, 0, 0, 0]`? The solution is to split at the equal sign then. See the updated answer.

Comment: You have come through yet again. Thank you for your time. It is very much appreciated.